# Como rotacionar uma imagem sem saber o ângulo de inclinação?

Tags: python, processamento-de-imagens

Meu programa recebe uma imagem de uma CNH escaneada(com o papel de fundo). O objetivo é remover o fundo e deixar apenas a CNH. Quando o documento está na vertical, não há problema, já que posso usar o getbbox, como fiz no código abaixo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as pli
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu as otsu
from PIL import Image

cnh_cinza = Image.open("cnh.jpg").convert('L')
cnh_cinza.save('cnhcinza.jpg')

img = pli.imread('cnhcinza.jpg')
imagem = Image.open('cnhcinza.jpg')


limiar = otsu(img)

mask = img < limiar

msk = Image.fromarray(mask,'L')

caixa = msk.getbbox()

corte = imagem.crop(caixa)



_,ax = plt.subplots (1,3)
ax[0].imshow (img,cmap='gray')
ax[1].imshow (mask,cmap='gray')
ax[2].imshow (corte,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[Imagem removida]

Quando o documento está inclinado, a função getbbox não funciona, ou seja, não consigo recortar o documento.

Como posso contornar esse problema?

Agradeço a colaboração.

Answer (score 6):

Para rotacionar uma imagem sem saber o ângulo você precisa **estimar a inclinação** ([na documentação](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_geometric.html), leia o tópico "*Parameter Estimation*"). Essa estimação trabalha comparando pontos notáveis entre uma "origem" (a imagem "ideal", em que a CNH está posicionada como esperado) e um "destino" (a imagem real que você tem, com a CNH toda torta).

> Ou seja, não tem milagre: mesmo não sabendo a inclinação você ainda
>   assim precisa saber onde estão esses pontos na imagem que estiver
>   processando.

Considere, a seguir, o exemplo que eu preparei. A imagem tem tamanho 930 x 659 e a CNH está rotacionada em um ângulo qualquer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O seguinte código faz o "ajuste":

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import misc
import numpy as np
from skimage import transform as tf

src = np.array((
    (155, 110),
    (774, 110),
    (155, 548),
    (774, 548)
))
dst = np.array((
    (94, 248),
    (664, 7),
    (266, 651),
    (835, 410)
))

tform3 = tf.ProjectiveTransform()
tform3.estimate(src, dst)

cnh = misc.imread("cnh2.jpg")
cnh_ajustada = tf.warp(cnh, tform3, output_shape=(930, 1000))
misc.imsave('cnh2-ajustada.jpg', cnh_ajustada)

_,ax = plt.subplots (1,2)
ax[0].imshow (cnh)
ax[0].plot(dst[:, 0], dst[:, 1], '.r')
ax[1].imshow (cnh_ajustada)
ax[1].plot(src[:, 0], src[:, 1], '.r')
plt.show()
```

E produz o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare nessa última imagem (resultante do `plt.show()`) os pontos em vermelho. No lado esquerdo (sobre a imagem original) são plotados os pontos *definidos manualmente* na variável `dst` porque esses pontos são o "destino" da estimação (a imagem que se tem, como explicado anteriormente). E no lado direito (sobre a imagem final, ajustada) são plotados os pontos, também *definidos manualmente* na variável `src` porque esses são a "origem" da estimação (a imagem idealizada, também como explicado anteriormente).

Eu marquei os pontos manualmente porque é mais fácil para ilustrar o processo, mas no seu caso você irá precisar ser capaz de identificá-los automaticamente de alguma forma. Os valores de `src` são fáceis: vc pode mantê-los fixos! (observe o exemplo na documentação, como esse parâmetro tem exatamente o tamanho da imagem final). Assim, a estimação de transformação vai incluir não só a rotação e a translação como também a escala, se necessário (isto é, vai alterar o tamanho da imagem final se, por caso, a imagem original estiver com a CNH maior ou menor). Já os valores de `dst` vão requerer algum esforço adicional.

Se a sua imagem é bem "comportada" (isto é, o fundo é uniforme e branco, etc), deve ser possível identificar tais pontos procurando pelos cantos da imagem segmentada (leia sobre "*corner detection*" [na documentação](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_corner.html)). Isso funciona porque o objeto de interesse do seu domínio de problema é fixo (isto é, ele é sempre um documento retangular). :)

Outra alternativa, bem mais simples, é você simplesmente solicitar ao usuário que selecione/marque interativamente na imagem capturada onde estão os seus cantos. Muitos sistemas de software fazem isso, já que requer apenas 4 cliques do usuário.

Comment: Bem legal - é provável que para o tipo de imagens dessa pergunta em particular, a detecção de cantos funcione e seja possível automatizar todo o processo, como o O.P. pediu